# Why the program doesn't get into an infinite loop by adding super.viewdidload()?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Why doesn't the program read the `super.viewDidLoad()` while running itself and therefore doesn't get into an infinite loop ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Because it calls `super` not it`self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `super.viewDidLoad()` in your override of this method, it is calling the superclass implementation of this method, not calling your implementation again. So there is no infinite loop.

This practice of calling `super` ensures that although you may override the method in question, that you will make sure that you code will still perform whatever (if anything) the superclass did in its implementation. You don’t want to accidentally lose/change some basic view controller behavior in your subclass just because you happened to override some methods.

This begs the question, “do I *have* to call the `super` implementation when I override a method?”

In general, for these lifecycle events, yes, if one overrides a method, one should call `super` implementation unless the documentation for that particular method advises otherwise. (I know, it would be nice if it were a hard and fast rule, but the reality is that you should just refer to the documentation, method by method.)

That having been said, the documentation for these methods generally warns us when it’s absolutely essential to call `super` rendition. E.g., [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) for `viewDidAppear(_:)` is explicit (emphasis added):

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view. If you override this method, *you must call `super` at some point in your implementation.*

It’s also pretty clear in those rare cases that one really shouldn’t call it. E.g. [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) for `loadView` (not to be confused with `viewDidLoad`) explicitly warns us:

> Your custom implementation of this method should *not* call `super`.

As a general rule, when you override a method, you want to ensure that you don’t change the superclass behavior (in the spirit of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). And unless you know for a fact that the `super` method does nothing (and never will), you really should generally call `super` rendition unless there is a very specific reason (such as explicit counsel in the documentation not to).

Comment: So can I even copy viewDidLoad() definition from UIViewController and still the program is compilable ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “copy ... definition”. When you override a method, the method signature (the name, parameters, return value, etc.) is, by definition, exactly the same as that of the base class implementation. But when you override, you’re effectively replacing the base class implementation with your own (thereby losing whatever that `super` implementation did, if anything). So we explicitly call `super` rendition in our subclass implementation so that when `viewDidLoad` is eventually called, it does everything in our override as well as what was in the base class implementation.

Comment: Thanks U. 
I got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

`super.viewDidLoad()` means that it calls the method `viewDidLoad()` inherited from the superclass. The `override` is happening in the subclass.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // First call the viewDidLoad() from the superclass
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Run the rest in the subclass
}
```

Comment: Why it is needed to run viewDidLoad() from the superclass ?

Comment: @ParsaNoori It is not needed

Comment: @ParsaNoori It's needed because the superclass may need to do its own setup. Failure to call `super.viewDidLoad()` (or whatever the method may be) can leave the class improperly setup. In most cases you should always call `super.xxx()` when you override the `xxx` method in a base class. `UIViewController loadView` is one example where you are specifically told not to call `super.loadView()`. But that's a rare case.